# How to write an SQLite3 Objective-C resultset wrapper?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I want to write an SQLite resultset wrapper class for iPhone to dynamically call `sqlite3_column_int` or `sqlite3_column_text`. In my `fetchAll` method I would like without knowing data type to just return the data.

I was thinking of using `performSelector`. How would I design such a class to interact with SQLite?

Comment: An interesting mental exercise, but one not well suited to SQLite. On the one hand, use Core Data.  However, if you want arbitrary persistence of non-typed data, you are better off rolling your own or using a different solution than SQLite.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't use an Objective-C feature to call a C function in that way (performSelector that is).  You can call C code within objective-C.  One approach may be to keep function pointers to the C functions you want to call, then implement some logic to choose the appropriate function pointer to reference.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure I understand, but I suppose you might be able to write a few Objective-C methods containing small amounts of pure C and call performSelector on those. Unfortunately the SQLite3 API for the iPhone kind of sucks.